# I want to create a one time reporting job that generate day wise orders placed and and revenue earned for last 5 days. please help me

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a one time reporting job that generate day wise orders placed and and revenue earned for last 5 days. please help me.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT order_date,
  COUNT(web_order_number) AS num_orders,
  SUM(order_total)        AS daily_total
FROM purchase_orders_owner
WHERE order_date>=date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY order_date;
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT order_date ,
  COUNT(web_order_number) AS num_orders ,
  SUM(order_total)        AS daily_total
FROM purchase_orders_owner
GROUP BY DATE(order_date)
```

Comment: Help me guys... is there any modification in above quries..

Comment: So you want all orders of the past five days. With their corresponding revenue ordered by the day they were placed?
Start of with some info of how your table looks like.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?  Your query is tagged "oracle", but the syntax uses MySQL functions.

Comment: i am using oracle...

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you would do this as:

```
SELECT trunc(order_date) as order_date,
       COUNT(web_order_number) AS num_orders,
       SUM(order_total)        AS daily_total
FROM purchase_orders_owner
WHERE order_date >= trunc(sysdate - 5)
GROUP BY trunc(order_date);
```

Your queries use MySQL functions that Oracle does not support.